# Maven dependencies all in one file

Tags: java, maven, configuration, dependencies, version

In my workspace there are many Maven projects.
It is possible to list all the dependencies' versions in one file and tell Maven to read them from it?
So I'll have a `***.properties` (I'm guessing the extection) in substitution of

`<properties>
....
</properties>`

in my poms.

EDIT: currently I have a pom parent and several child poms. I want to have the versions in a external file instead of the parent pom.

Comment: You want a sharing between projects, not modules, right? *(because in the 2nd situation you can use a `group-id` and a `dependency` ...)*

Answer (score 0):

Use the command:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create parent maven project that would list your dependencies versions.

Then on every project's pom.xml you would refer a `<parent>...</parent>` that would allow to inherit all the properties and then use these properties.

Parent could be:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleParent01</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.3</spring.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And your project would refer to it like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleParent01</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>org.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>SampleProject01</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Yeah that's how I have now. Mabye I didn't explain enough what I have. I want a file separately from the parent pom